# How to make a model for a json array in extjs?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

The data I'm getting back from my server looks like:

```
["admin", "user", "developer", "super"]
```

And I'm trying to map that into this model:

```
Ext.define('RoleModel', {
      extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
      //fields: [{}]
});
```

My store looks like this:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      model: 'RoleModel',
      proxy: {
          type: 'ajax',
          url : '/roles',
          reader: {
              type: 'json'
          }
      },
      autoLoad: true
  });
```

How can I map the single array I'm getting from the server into my `RoleModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got it, before your *JSON* can be parsed into your data model it needs to be in the form:

```js
[
    { "role": "admin"     },
    { "role": "user"      }, 
    { "role": "developer" }, 
    { "role": "super"     }
]
```

... but if you're rocking ExtJS ***5.x*** you don't need to manually make the Ajax call - you can apply a ***transform*** on the proxy's reader, for example:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'RoleModel', 
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/roles',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            transform: function(data) {
                return data.map(function(x){ 
                    return { role: x }; 
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7q5)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a role field to my model and doing something like:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '/roles',
  success: function(response){
    var json = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    var jsonObj = json.map(function(r){ return {role: r}});
    store.loadData(jsonObj);
  }
});
```